# Month wise archive query for wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display my monthly archive like home page (Magazine Type). I used this following query

```
    $day = date('d');
    $month = date('m');
    $year = date('Y');

query_posts("cat=2&year=$year&monthnum=$month&day=$day&order=ASC");
?>
```

By using this query I'm able get the post of current month. When I select previous month, there also show the post of current month.
what can I do?
can anyone help us with this query?

This is my monthly category page :http://www.chintasutra.com/2015/08/

Comment: if you want to build a custom query, better to try with [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), then just pass the parameters [category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters), [date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), [order](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) for example